# Javascript callback vs inline initialing 'callback'

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, I have gone through tutorials about callbacks, but I don't see any that answers this, both method below offers the same results, the only difference I see is callback allows dynamically passing in a callback function.

Are there other advantages, I am missing?

Thank you.

**Callback**

```
function logOne(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("one");
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}

function logTwo() {
  console.log("two");
}
logOne(logTwo); // one, two
```

**No Callback**

```
function logOne() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("one");
    logTwo();
  }, 1000);
}

function logTwo() {
  console.log("two");
}
logOne(); // one, two
```

Comment: With your first code-block you can pass any function you want to execute after 1s, allowing you to call logOne(fn1), logOne(fn2) with two different functions (fn1 and fn2), however, with your second code-block you're only limited to running `logTwo()`.

Comment: The difference is in its intention.

Comment: @Estradiaz - Ooooh, nicely put.

Comment: Thanks, guys for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is more flexible: You can use any callback, not just `logTwo`.

Both have their uses, it depends on whether you need the flexibility or whether `logOne` should be specifically tied to `logTwo`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Callback of function**: If you want to do some operation on some event
> Like show time on click of a button. Then you override onclick
> function for that button. So whenever (independent on time) that
> button is clicked, that application internal framework will call
> onclick event and your onclick function will be called.
>
> **Normal function** : Every function is normal function
>
> **Calling a function** is when you actually do the function.
>
> **Passing a function** is when function A needs function B in order to
> work. So when you call function A, you pass it function B as an
> argument. In this case you are not calling function B, instead you are
> providing it to function A so that function A can call it.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example create a tight coupling between logOne and logTwo functions. This way you end up with a logOne function that can't be reused since it only works with one exact function.

By passing a callback, you make your function more flexible and generalized. Now it is able to work with a wide range of other functions as long as they have the same "shape" - same number of arguments in a same order.